# Windows phone: date picker and button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datepicker, windows-phone-toolkit

Is it possible to have a hidden date picker in windows phone and show it with a button. I have this code

```
InitializeComponent();
this.datePicker1.ValueChanged += new EventHandler<DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs>(datePicker1_ValueChanged);
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
button1.Content = date.ToShortDateString();
...

private void datePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date1 = (DateTime)e.NewDateTime;
    button1.Content = date1.ToShortDateString();
}
```

but how do I launch the date picker with the button.

Comment: Please review the formatting of your code snippets. It is difficult to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use custom (and cool) date/time pickers from [Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/) like [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization).